# Grabing Mailbox Stats : How can I look at multiple OUs?

Tags: powershell

I have this Powershell code that grabs the mailbox stats from one OrganisationalUnit but how could I grab it from two others without running the code again seperately. How would I create an array of OUs inside the forloop?

Also how would I order the results so that its the highest usage at the top?

```
$(Foreach ($mailbox in Get-Recipient -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit 

"Users" -RecipientType UserMailbox){
$Stat = $mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select TotalItemSize,ItemCount
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    FirstName = $mailbox.FirstName
    LastName = $mailbox.LastName
    DisplayName = $mailbox.DisplayName
    TotalItemSize = $Stat.TotalItemSize
    ItemCount = $Stat.ItemCount
    PrimarySmtpAddress = $mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Alias = $mailbox.Alias
}
}) | Select FirstName,LastName,DisplayName,TotalItemSize,ItemCount,PrimarySmtpAddress,Alias | Export-CSV e:\MailboxSizeReport.csv -NTI
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try for a fix, which I cannot test as I don't have your environment.

I've added an array of OUs and perform a ForEach to retrieve OU names before passing them to your code. BTW I used -append in the Export-CSV which requires Powershell V3, let me know if you still run V2.

```
$OUs = @("users","managers","admins","VIPs","rest of the world")

Foreach ($OU in $OUs)
{
   $(Foreach ($mailbox in Get-Recipient -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit $OU -RecipientType UserMailbox)
   {
       $Stat = $mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select TotalItemSize,ItemCount

       New-Object PSObject -Property @{
           FirstName = $mailbox.FirstName
           LastName = $mailbox.LastName
           DisplayName = $mailbox.DisplayName
           TotalItemSize = $Stat.TotalItemSize
           ItemCount = $Stat.ItemCount
           PrimarySmtpAddress = $mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress
           Alias = $mailbox.Alias
       }
   }) | Select FirstName,LastName,DisplayName,TotalItemSize,ItemCount,PrimarySmtpAddress,Alias | Export-CSV e:\MailboxSizeReport.csv -NTI -append
}
```